# Wordpress how to display hierarchy of pages with a WP Query-Parent->Child Relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hierarchical-data, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm currently trying to fetch all my pages from different post types and display them on a single page with a WP Query but I wanted to display them in such a template in the HTML instead of it all coming as a big list of course I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible

```
 Parent 
    Child 
 Parent 
    Child 
 Parent 
 Parent 
 Parent
```

This is what I'm using so far

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'page',
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 20, 
    );
    $result = new WP_Query($args);
?>
    <section>
    <h2><?php echo $post_type; ?></h2>
        <?php
        while ($result->have_posts()) { 
            $result->the_post();
            $post = get_post();
            ?>
                <ul>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href=""><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>
   </section>
   <?php }
```

I tried using `wp_list_pages` but I'm not sure how to use that for different post types and also I would like to have limited posts per page not display everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query` is not the right tool for the job!

Wordpress has special functions for what you're looking for:

> [`get_pages`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/)
> [`wp_list_pages`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/)

> "I tried using wp_list_pages but I'm not sure how to use that for different post types"

Well, that's why docs are here for!

For example, `wp_list_pages` accept an argument called `post_type` which lets you specify which "post type" you're interested in, and its default value is the wordpress "page" type. If you want to change it to your custom post type then you could use something like this:

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type'
);

wp_list_pages($args);
```

---

> "also I would like to have limited posts per page not display everything"

Again, there is docs for that!

if you use `get_pages` for example, then there is an argument for limiting the number of pages shown on the page and that's called `number`. The `number` argument is an integer and represents the number of pages to return and its default is `0`(all pages).

Using `get_pages` also you could specify your custom post type to query. The argument for that is called `post_type` and its default value is the wordpress "page" type.

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
  'number'    => 20
);

$your_pages = get_pages($args);

foreach ($your_pages as $page) {
  echo $page->post_title;
}
```

---

If you really need/want to use `WP_Qery` then you could do it like this:

`WP_Qery` + `get_pages`

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'orderby'    => 'title',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order'    => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
);

$results = new WP_Query($args);

if ($results) {
  while ($results->have_posts()) {
    $results->the_post();

    echo "<h3>" . get_the_title() . "<h3>";

    $sub_pages_args = array(
      'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
    );

    $sub_pages = get_pages($sub_pages_args);

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($sub_pages as $sub_page) {
      echo "<li>";
      echo $sub_page->post_title;
      echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Which will output this:

```
 Parent Title
    Child Title
 Parent Title
    Child Title
 Parent Title
 Parent Title
 Parent Title
```

Fully tested and works on wordpress `5.8`.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much I really tried it by following the documentation but I couldn't exactly figure it out I think I couldn't understand it as well from there but your description was perfect I understood it all, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pages = get_pages();
if ($pages) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page->post_parent == 0) {
            echo $page->post_title . ' — ' . $page->ID;
            $sub_pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $page->ID));
            foreach ($sub_pages as $sub_page) {
                echo ' — ' . $sub_page->post_title . ' — ' . $sub_page->ID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).